# If a function $f(x,t)$ is globally Lipschitz, does that implies that it is continuously differentiable in $x$?

Tags: derivatives, lipschitz-functions

I know that it is necessary that $df/dx$ continuously exists and it has to be uniformly bounded  for $f(x,t)$ to be globally Lipschitz. But, if a function $f(x,t)$ is globally Lipschitz, does that implies that it is continuously differentiable in $x$ ?

Comment: The first sentence of your post is incorrect. See my answer for the correct statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x,t)=|x|$ is globally Lipschitz,but not continuously differentiable (not even differentiable in $(0,t)$ for any $t$).

What is correct though (I think that's what you mean in the first sentence) that if $f$ is globally Lipschitz **and if $\partial f/\partial x$ exists**, then this derivative is uniformly bounded. This just follows by writing down the difference quotient and using the Lipschitz assumption.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was some mistakes in the book I was studying. But looks like my teacher was wrong. Gonna take this to class for discussion.